# How to show that the real eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix are 1 or -1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $A$ be an orthogonal matrix, and let $λ$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Prove $λ=1$ or $λ=-1$.

What I did was, as $A$ is orthogonal we know the following holds: $$\lVert Av\rVert = \lVert v\rVert \implies \left(Av,Av\right)=\left(v,v\right) \implies \frac{\left(Av,Av\right)}{\left(v,v\right)}=1.$$ Then,
$$Av=λv \implies \lVert Av\rVert =\lVert λv\rVert \implies \left(Av,Av\right)=\left(λv,λv\right)\implies \frac{\left(Av,Av\right)}{\left(v,v\right)}=λ$$ which means $λ$ must equal $1$. What am I missing?

Edit for future readers:

The correct way to get $λ$ out of the inner product should have been

$$\left(λv,λv\right) \implies λ\left(v,λv\right)\implies λ\left(λv,v\right) \implies \ λ^{2}\left(v,v\right).$$

Comment: That will be $|λ|^2$

Comment: The statement is false. $A$ may have complex eigenvalues. The correct conclusion should be $|\lambda| = 1$.

Comment: When regarding $A$ as only a real matrix, or even a matrix of a linear operator on a real linear space, then $A$ could only have real eigenvalues, i.e. those $Ay = \lambda y$ for **only $\lambda \in \Bbb R$**.

Comment: @xbh Consider real orthogonal matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2} \\ -\sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}/2$. Are its eigenvalues real or complex?

Comment: @Zhanxiong I know what you mean. But someone may require both eigenvectors and eigenvalues be real.

Comment: @Rkb Of course! I've missed the most obvious thing.. Have to polish these basic definitions. :(

Comment: I should have mentioned the question is regarding real numbers only..

Comment: @xbh My comment just applies to OP's original statement, without further information, it is definitely false.

Comment: Your error is in the final implication. From $\langle Av,Av\rangle = \langle\lambda v,\lambda v\rangle$, you get $\langle Av,Av\rangle = \lambda\overline{\lambda}\langle v,v\rangle$, by pulling out $\lambda$ once from each entry of the inner product.

Comment: As others have said, even though $A$ may have only real entries, its eigenvalues may be complex.  A rotation matrix is orthogonal, but its eigenvalues (in non-trivial cases) are complex conjugates.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Hi can you explain the bar above the second λ? what does it mean, and why is it not just λ?

Comment: It's complex conjugation; if $\lambda$ is real, $\overline{\lambda}=\lambda$ and $\lambda\overline{\lambda}=\lambda^2$. If $\lambda$ is complex, then $\lambda\overline{\lambda}=|\lambda|^2$.